# Why is the Data in my Computed Columns showing up with null / 0 values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

I need to create a query that shows the average productivity for editors that have worked on more than one book except for their first book published with a precision of 0.01 pages/day.

I have the correct columns showing now but the computed column is not showing any of the calculated averages.

The columns to be displayed are

`EditorName`

`BookName`

computed column `AverageProductivity`

Here are the tables and their columns

```
AGENT  AgentID (PK,varchar(11), not null)
       AgentName (varchar(25), not null)

BOOK   BookName (PK, varchar(45), not null)
       Genre (varchar(25), not null)
       DateOfPublication (date, not null)
       NoOfPages (int, not null)
       WriterID (PK, FK,, varchar(11), not null)
       EditorID (FK, varchar(11), not null)

EDITOR EditorID (PK, varchar(11), not null)
       EditorName (varchar(25), not null)
       Mentors_EditorID (FK, varchar(11), null)

WRITER WriterID (PK, varchar(11), not null)
       WriterName (varchar(25), not null)
       AgentID (FK, varchar(11), not null)
```

Sample Data

```
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('Valley of Heroes','10','Fiction','2010-01-12',874,'20');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('The Ruler''s Return','11','Fantasy','2012-03-14',765,'22');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('eRobot','11','Fantasy','2011-04-15',264,'20');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('An Uncle''s Letters','12','Fiction','2012-06-12',258,'20');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('Pretty flowers','13','Album','2013-01-31',148,'22');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('A Tale of Lions','12','Fantasy','2012-08-17',301,'21');
insert into BOOK (BookName, WriterID, Genre, DateOfPublication, NoOfPages, EditorID)
values ('eRobot','13','Sci Fi','2012-10-04',465,'23');
```

Here is the Query...

```
select * from (
    select 
    e.EditorName,
    b.BookName,
    round(
        NoOfPages/datediff(
            day, 
            lag(b.DateOfPublication) over(partition by b.EditorID order by b.DateOfPublication),
            DateOfPublication
        ),
        2
    ) AverageProductivity       
from book b
inner join editor e on e.EditorID = b.EditorID 
) x where AverageProductivity is not null
```

Results...

```
Melanie eRobot  0
Melanie An Uncle's Letters  0
George  Pretty flowers  0
```

Comment: Integer maths. An expression made up of integers can only return an integer. `0.5` isn't an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division.  So, `1/2` is `0`, not `0.5`.

You can easily fix this in your code.  I think the simplest method is:

```
round(NoOfPages * 1.0 /
      datediff(day, 
               lag(b.DateOfPublication) over(partition by b.EditorID order by b.DateOfPublication),
               DateOfPublication
              ), 2
     )
```

The `* 1.0` converts this to a number with decimal places, getting around the integer division problem.

Comment: awsome, that works. is there a way that I can tunicate all the extra zeros?

Comment: @YHapticY . . . I don't know what you mean by "tunicate all the extra zeros".  You might want to ask a new question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: alright thank you for your help