# SQL 2017 rounds of decimal number using "FLOOR" function

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have been calculating different integer percentages with different numbers but each time I get floor rounded number. select  13*100/60 gives me 21 and the actual number is 21.66 which using a round function should give us 22 but it can only give me 21 for all different decimal numbers.

I am using SQL 2017. please help

Comment: This same problem was asked about only 20 minutes ago: [Why is the Data in my Computed Columns showing up with null / 0 values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58502938/3484879)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you are dividing `int`s and not floating-point numbers.  **Integer division returns an integer**.

Try the following instead (noting the `.0` on the end of the 60):

```
SELECT 13 * 100 / 60.0
```

Making one of the components a floating-point number will automatically output the result as a floating-point number.

Output:

```
21.666666
```

Incidentally, if you are working with variables and one of them is a `FLOAT`, it will automatically produce the output you expect:

```
DECLARE @A FLOAT
DECLARE @B INT
DECLARE @C INT

SET @A = 13
SET @B = 100
SET @C = 60

SELECT @A * @B / @C
```

Output:

```
21.6666666666667
```